# How to play video url from api request in flutter , i used video player package but not include back or exit screen?

Tags: flutter, video-player

I have Ali Json then there object called video I include url video so how to display this url in app , I use video player but full screen not work and can't control on ui to add button exit or button back in ui video player .

Comment: Hello, show us your code before anyone could try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use video_player along with [chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie), it has more control over the video.